# How do I best get multiple correct answers clarified?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, asking-questions

**Concrete example**

I was glad to find that my question was already asked and answered here:
[How to make Latexmk use makeglossaries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries)

But there are more than one(three) seemingly correct but different answers. I would like to pick the best answer, and use it myself. Normally the up-votes and acceptance from the questioner would tell me what answer to pick. - But here I believe that the difference in votes could be from the fact that the answers is given over lang time. To complicate the matter, there is a comment(from @mhp), that suggest an improvement(the -q option) - and I can not see if this improvement is really implemented.

---

Should I add comments to the answers, and hope the the question still receives some attension? Ask the answers directly?

A new question with the aim to find the optimal solution would unfortunately still be a disguised duplicate:o(

Comment: I think offering a bounty could help here: It will bring the question back into view, so there are likely going to be more votes on the different answers, which may help to clarify which answer is "best", and it will give the original answerers an incentive to revisit their posts to improve them, or to generate a new "canonical" answer.

Comment: @Jake: Brilliant idea - until now I thought that bounties was for your own unanswered questions. If you make your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think offering a bounty could help here: It will bring the question back into view, so there are likely going to be more votes on the different answers, which may help to clarify which answer is "best", and it will give the original answerers an incentive to revisit their posts to improve them, or to generate a new "canonical" answer.